# Using NVM installed Nodejs 16 for Jupyterlab extensions install on Centos 7.6

Tags: node.js, jupyter-lab

I tried to install the @jupyterlab/geojson-extension on a Jupyterlab Version 3.5.3 running on Jupyterhub on Centos 7.6. It gives an error message of “Please install nodejs >=12.0.0. nodejs may be installed using conda or directly from the nodejs website”. In looking at $node -v it shows v6.13.1. Ran $ conda install -c conda-forge nodejs to try and upgrade but it only installed node v6.13.1 on Centos 7.6 which seems to be the highest version conda can install on this OS. So next tried to install using NVM as root: $ nvm install lts/gallium . Now it gives $node -v as v16.20.2 . After restarting Jupyterhub it still shows in a Jupyter terminal node version is v6.13.1. Also $ whereis node
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/node /data/opt/anaconda3/bin/node . So apparently the jupyterhub is invoking node from /data/opt/anaconda3/bin/node which has old v6.13.1 instead of from /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2 since NVM installs under the userid . Jupyterhub is running under root user and how to make it use the node in /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2 instead of /data/opt/anaconda3/bin/node . Thanks!